# Android - Make Navigation Bar disappear

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme, android-styles

I' ve been searching for a while and i cannot find a way to make the nav bar dissapear in android application. Here is my resources from android studio

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<style name="AppTheme.CustomPop">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

and the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.....maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >

    <activity
        android:name=".Class"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomPop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

and what i get here

[image]

I want the bar with Maps string to dissapear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide or show notification bar using flags

to hide :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

to show :

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

now for actionBar :

to hide :

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

to show :

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: Yes! That dit it. The other answers crushes my application. Thanks Souiane!

Answer (score 0):

Place this line

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Right after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

in your Activity onCreate method.